I tried to find the boundary of $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\:|\:x_n\geq 0 \}$ which is a subset of $R^n$
The set A is defined by $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\:|\:x_n\geq 0 \}$.
I first pick any $r\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$, after that i defined B as
$$B=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n \:\vert\: y_n=0 \}$$
Then i obtained the ball  $B(r,z)$ for any $z\in B$ such that $z=(z_1,...,0)$
For the ball i obtained i noticed that for some $a=(z_1,...,\frac{-r}{2})$ we have:
$$d(a,z)=\sqrt{(a_1-z_1)^2+...+(\frac{-r}{2}-0)^2}=\frac{r}{2}$$
Since we already defined $a_i=z_i$ for all $i$ except $i=n$ and furthermore notice that we can change $a_n$ as $\frac{r}{2}$ (call it $c$) instead of what we have done.
By definition of $A$
$$a\in B(r,z)\Rightarrow a\notin A$$ since $a_n<0$.
But for some $c=(z_1,\ldots,\frac{r}{2})$ I mentioned:
$$c\in B(r,z) \Rightarrow c\in A$$ since $c_n>0$.
Thus the set $B\subseteq \partial A$ , for the part of the proof that finding $B=\partial A$.
Is seeing the $B=\text{cl}(A^c)\cap\text{cl}(A)$ is enough or I need some other steps?

The easiest way to do it is to check that all other points $a\in A$ are inner points, i.e. there exists some ball around them completely contained in $A$. Of course, you pick the radius of this ball as, say half, of the $n$'th coordinate of $a$.

The set A is defined by A=$\{$x$\in$ $\mathbb{R}^n : x_n\geq 0 \}$.
I first pick any $r\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$, after that i defined B as
$B=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n \vert y_n=0 \}$
Then i obtained the ball  $B(r,z)$ for any $z\in B$ such that
z=($z_1,...,0$)
For the ball i obtained i noticed that for some a=$(z_1,...,\frac{-r}{2})$ we have:
$d(a,z)=\sqrt{(a_1-z_1)^2+...+(\frac{-r}{2}-0)^2}=\frac{r}{2}$
Since we already defined $a_i=z_i$ for all $i$ except $i=n$ and furthermore notice that we can change $a_n$ as $\frac{r}{2}$(call it $c$) instead of what we have done.
By definition of A,
$a\in B(r,z)\Rightarrow a\notin A$
But for some c=($z_1$,...,$\frac{r}{2}$) i mentioned:
$  c\in B(r,z) \Rightarrow c\in A $
Thus the set B$\subseteq \partial$A ,For the part of the proof that finding B=$\partial$A; Pick any x$\in$$B^c$
then either $x_n<0$ or $x_n>0$ where we can obtain balls as,
$R(\rho,x)=\{z\in\mathbb{R}^n \vert d(z,x)<r \}$
for some $\rho$=$\frac{\vert x_n\vert}{2}$ and for all z$\in$R($\rho$,x) observe that;
$\vert x_n-z_n \vert<\rho=\frac{\vert x_n \vert}{2}$
then for x$\in$A and not in B we have
$x_n>0$ and $z_n-\frac{x_n}{2}<x_n<z_n+\frac{x_n}{2}\Rightarrow z_n>\frac{x_n}{2}\Rightarrow z_n>0 $ hence z is in A and not B
so R($\rho$,x)$\subseteq$int(A) which gets us to,
$A/B=$int(A) implies that B=$\partial$A

I used a box instead of some ball since every box contains a ball inside.
